# Read .csv file, store in SQL database?

Tags: c#, sql, csv, blob

For a programming asignment, I am to program a prototype.
Right now I'm only looking to code 1 method.
The method is supposed to read a locale .csv file, and save it as a BLOB (Binary Large Object) in a database on an external server.
However, I'm quite new at C#, and I am used to Java. I'm not exactly sure what a BLOB is, some sort of Byte Array or something?

So far my program can

- Connect to the SQL server.
- Read the .csv file.

The database table is called tblUsers.

The field I'm trying to insert it into is BlobFile, which is of datatype varbinary(8000).

I don't even know if the datatype is correct.

**All I want is the .csv file saved into a table on a server.**

"String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated."
Is what I get unfortunately, which I can figure out means that my .csv file somewhat doesn't match with my datatype in the table.
I don't know how to link you to the .csv but it looks like:

```
4.012 3.012 1.312 3.321 4.232
```

and so on.
This is the C# code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication8
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filePath = "C:/Users/Soeren/Desktop/epilepsi - semester/EpilepsiEKG/Patient1_Reciprocal_HFpower_x1.csv";
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        string line = fs.ReadLine();
        string[] value = line.Split(',');
        BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(fs);


        byte[] BlobValue = reader.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
        fs.Close();
        reader.Close();
        //FILE READ!

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=webhotel10.iha.dk;Initial Catalog=F13ST2ITS2201270867;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=F13ST2ITS2201270867;Password=F13ST2ITS2201270867");
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("insert into tblUsers(BlobFilename,BlobFile) values(@BlobFilename,@Blobfile)", con);
        SqlParameter BlobFileNameParam = new SqlParameter("@BlobFileName", SqlDbType.NChar);
        SqlParameter BlobFileParam = new SqlParameter("@BlobFile", SqlDbType.Binary);
        com.Parameters.Add(BlobFileNameParam);
        com.Parameters.Add(BlobFileParam);

        BlobFileNameParam.Value = filePath.Substring(filePath.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);

        BlobFileParam.Value = BlobValue;

        try
        {

            com.Connection.Open();
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show(BlobFileNameParam.Value.ToString() + " saved to database.", "BLOB Saved", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

        }


        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Save Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

        }


        finally
        {

            com.Connection.Close();

        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: That being said, the error message **String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated.** actually spells out what is wrong. You are trying to insert too much data into a field that has a specific dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the BlobFileParam Parameter is declared, it is a fixed length binary Parameter with size 0 (as the size is not specified). You try to insert data with a length greater than the specified size (0). 
Try setting the size property of the parameter BlobFileParam to the correct length; I also think the SqlDbType.VarBinary might be a better choice for the type of the parameter.

Comment: This is useful. My problem is that my .csv file changes size, it is variable. So the size attribute - what is that in this case? Is it the maximum size?

Comment: I think that changing the Parameter type to VarBinary along with a size of 8000 (as defined in the database) should work. The Parameter type and size then matches the database Definition.

Comment: SqlParameter BlobFileParam = new SqlParameter("@BlobFile", SqlDbType.VarBinary, 8000);

It doesn't work. Same error. :(

Comment: I just checked the other Parameter also. It is of type NChar, it should also be NVarChar. This might also be the source of the error.

Comment: This works! Solved.
I think I owe you some beers, holla at me if you come through Aarhus in Denmark lol

Comment: Thanks for the invitation. Please accept the answer if it works. Thank you.